# Symfony form async data for select

Tags: php, symfony

Изучаю symfony. У меня есть следующая задача, которую пытаюсь решить

1. Пользователь заходит на страницу
2. На странице отображается форма
3. На фоне отправляется запрос на другой сервер (около 5 секунд)
4. Пока идёт запрос на другой сервер, пользователю отображается сообщение подождать
5. Когда приходят данные с сервера, они подгружаются в select в форме

Т.к. запрос на другой сервер довольно длительный (около 5 секунд), решил подгружать эти данные асинхронно, чтобы пользователь не думал, что весь сайт завис и т.п.

Когда я решал эту задачу раньше на laravel, то использовал vue.js - открывается страница, отображается компонент, идёт запрос через axios ну и т.п.. Но в symfony есть мощные формы. Простенькую форму я с их помощью уже сделал, а тут что-то посложнее. Вроде бы есть какие-то слушатели событий.. В общем, я бы хотел узнать, реально ли мою задачу решить только используя возможности форм symfony 5? Или же следует использовать тот же vue.js? И как это можно сделать, если ответ положительный.

Comment: для асинхронности вам придётся использовать vue, иначе вам сервер будет отдавать страницу 5 секунд